# Graphic Layout not displaying correctly

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm setting up two small buttons but in the graphic layout the text comes cut off

[image]

But when I run the app the text displays correctly or at least how it is expected.

[image]

I know this might be an eclipse configuration but I can't seem to find it.

Any ideas?

Edit: I forgot to add the xml configuration.
http://textdump.net/read/4292/

Comment: please share the code of xml.

Comment: No worry. **Graphic Layout Editor isn't reliable**. That's all. Always have a run and see how it comes out for real.

Comment: Are display settings of Preview inside Eclipse identical to your device display?